# Copy maven dependencies within Java code

Tags: java, maven

There are very few documentations and examples on this (those exists are useless).

I would like to copy all the dependencies of a given pom.xml file. Usually, I can use `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` on command line  or use `maven-dependecy-plugin` configuration in the pom file.

However, I would like to do it programmatically on a given pom.xml file. So far, I figured that I will need to use `MavenCli`

```
MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
cli.doMain(new String[]{"clean", "dependency:copy-dependencies", "-DincludeScope=runtime"}, "C:\\workspace\\gui", null, null);
```

where `"C:\\workspace\\gui"` is a directory containing a pom.xml

but the above code gives me the following error:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test-pom: Could not resolve dependencies for project gigadot:test-pom:jar:0.5-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 (compile), commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1 (compile), org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1 (compile), org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2 (compile), xom:xom:jar:1.2.5 (compile), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16 (provided)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.commons:commons-math:pom:2.2 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): No connector available to access repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) of type default using the available factories -> [Help 1]
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910162/how-to-get-an-artifact-download-url-via-maven-api can gives some pointers?

Comment: Given that the pom is just an xml file, you could just use a dom library (like dom4j) and an xpath expression to grab all dependencies - just out of interest, why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Romski doing what you said will not include the transitive dependencies. The reason I wanted to do this is because I was building dynamic plugable system. I would like the dependencies of the jar plugin to be included in the classpath automatically.

Comment: In doxia there exists macros - could you use this?
http://maven.apache.org/doxia/macros/index.html#Snippet_Macro

Or writing you an owned maven plugin mojo? If so, maybe there is a api to get the dependency information via maven project Class?

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency to MavenCLI project

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-connector-wagon</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-http-lightweight</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```